# Accessing private methods or variables of outer class from inner class

Tags: java

Inner classes can even access the private variables/methods of outer classes. Then why I am getting compiler error when I am trying to access the private method of outer class object from inner class object in my code.

```
     public class OuterClass {

private int id=5;
private void printSomeText()
{
    System.out.println("Text is ");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
    outer.printSomeText();
    OuterClass.InnerClass inner = outer.new InnerClass();
    inner.printSomeText();// gives compiler error


}

 class InnerClass{

public void printText() {
    System.out.println("Some Text");

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Inner classes can even access the private variables/methods of outer classes.

Yes, which means that in your `InnerClass::printText` method, you can call:

```
OuterClass.this.printSomeText(); //private method is accessible
```

However to be able to write `inner.printSomeText();`, `InnerClass` would need its own `printSomeText` method, either declared in the class itself or inherited from a parent class.